# How can I use my private shuffle

Tags: java, methods

My problem is that I cant seem to use my `shuffle()` method which is a `private` (has to be private) within the `CardDeck` class. Not too sure whether should I use it in the `drawNextCard()` method or use it in the `CardDeck()` constructor. I'm also not too sure if my coding are right either. Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;
public class CardDeck
{
    private String[] ranks = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                    "J", "Q", "K", "A" };
    private char[] suits = {'s','h','d','c'};
    private Card[] cards = new Card[13];
    private int currentCard;

    CardDeck()
    {
        Card newCard;

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<13; j++)
            {
                cards[j] = new Card(this.ranks[j], this.suits[i]);
            }
        }

    }

    public void testing() //just for testing 
    {
        System.out.println(this.suits[0]);
    }   

    public Card drawNextCard()
    {
        return cards[currentCard++];
    }

    private void shuffle()
    {
        Card[] tmp = new Card[200];
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++)
        {
            int index = i + (int)(Math.random() * (cards.length));

            tmp[i] = cards[i];
            cards[i] = cards[index];
            cards[index] = tmp[i];
        } 
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class BlackJoker
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CardDeck cardDeck = new CardDeck();

        cardDeck.testing();
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
        System.out.println(cardDeck.drawNextCard());
    }
}
```

My output for testing would be

```
s
2c
3c
4c
5c
6c
7c
```

Comment: How are you trying to use `shuffle()`? You never call it in this code.

Comment: Also: your deck of cards should probably be 52 cards long. You create 13 cards and then overwrite them.

Comment: I simply do not see a problem here. It's just the way you want to implement it. If you want the card deck to be shuffled before taking the next card, you should call it inside `drawNextCard` method. Else if you want it to be shuffled only at the beginning only, call it in the constructor.

Comment: You can call your method in the constructor just fine. What's the issue with that? Also, not sure I see the need for the `tmp` array of some arbitrary size

Comment: Hello guys, Thank you for the responses.

Ok so I've tried to call the shuffle method inside the drawNextCard but I seem to get an error message by using this "Card.this.shuffle();". I've tried many possible ways of calling like "CardDeck.cards.shuffle();" or "this.shuffle();" but I get error messages like:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 53

Or

CardDeck.java:31: not an enclosing class: Card
                Card.this.shuffle();
                    ^

Comment: Why does `shuffle()` have to be `private`? Shuffling a deck is something to do _to_ a deck - it's functionality that should be exposed. The object doing the shuffling might be, for an example, a `Dealer`, or a `Player` with `nextUp == true`

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = i + (int)(Math.random() * (cards.length));
```

The reason you are getting IOB Exception is because of the above statement. The index for your cards can not exceed 12, but there is a chance the above statement may come up to be way beyond 12. So, here are possible options for the replacement of the above statement:

1. `int index = (int)(Math.random() * (cards.length));` The limitations would be- a card may be swapped with itself, and a card may be swapped back to the original position.
2. Another option is to use Collections.shuffle():

   `private void shuffle()
     {
         List<Card> cardList = Arrays.asList(cards);
         Collections.shuffle(cardList);
         cards = cardList.toArray(cards);
     }`

For your question in the comment part, on how to call shuffle, it depends on where you want to call it. If it's in the same class it's defined you just call it `shuffle();`. If it's in the main or another class, you call it after the instance of the class like `CardDeck cardDeck = new CardDeck();` `cardDeck.shuffle();`.